# ORA 1722 invalid number on date columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a line

```
TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')-A.CHANGE_DATE_EDITED AS AGE_LAST_DATE,
```

which is powered by the following line in an inner query

```
MAX(TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_CHAR(CSSH.CHANGE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')) as CHANGE_DATE_EDITED,
```

I keep stumbling into

```
ORA 1722: Invalid number
```

whenever I run the code, I tinkered with the code multiple times with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Addl info:

CSSH.CHANGE_DATE is a timestamp column

```
{RUN_DATE_YYYY-MM-DD}
```

is a date input parameter

I'm using Oracle 10g

Comment: What is the value of SELECT MAX(CSSH.CHANGE_DATE)

Comment: '02-MAY-15 08.08.10.000000000 AM' w/o the quotes

Answer (score 2):

What is the intention of your `max(to_date(trunc(to_char` expression?  And are you sure that `change_date` is a `timestamp` rather than a `date` as the name implies?

You explicitly cast the `timestamp` to a `varchar2` with the `to_char` call.  Then you call `trunc` but the string you pass in isn't a valid parameter if you're trying to truncate a `date`.  Assuming the intention there is to remove the time component, you'd want to pass no parameter or pass in something like `DD`.  Then you call `to_date` on a `date` which doesn't make any sense-- if that works, you'd have to implicitly cast the `date` to a `varchar2` in order to call `to_date` in order to, hopefully, get back the same `date` you started with.  Any of these implicit conversions are potentially ripe for throwing errors depending on things like your session's NLS settings.

My guess is that you really just want

```
max(cssh.change_date)
```

If you really want to eliminate the time component (in which case it would be pretty odd to want to store the data in a `timestamp` rather than a `date` in the first place),

```
trunc( max( cssh.change_date ))
```

Comment: @DavidAldridge - Good call.  Made that change.

Comment: Thanks @Justin-cave. Unfortunately, the datatype is indeed a timestamp. I understood that the trunc() would be buggy, at least where it is currently placed. I added it, albeit incorrectly, because I thought that the time component may be interfering with the age difference calculation, when I first encountered ORA: 1722. 
As to TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(
I read about it here (http://www.club-oracle.com/threads/convert-oracle-timestamp-to-date.692/) to convert timestamp to datetime and have been using a variant of it.